# vim: is possible to open a encrypted file using cli?

Tags: vim, encryption

Simple question.

With rar

```
rar X file.tar -p"mypass"
```

With 7z

```
7z X file.7z -p"mypass"
```

Vim can encrypt file using `:X`

and every time you want to open file

must use the password.

The question is: is possible to pass the pass as argument like rar and 7z?

A thing like this

```
vim filex.enc.txt -P"mypass"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `--cmd` you can give Vim a command to run before reading the file on the command line (as if it was part of your `~/.vimrc` file).  By setting the `key` option to the value of the encryption key in this way, you may give the encryption key on the command line:

```
$ vim --cmd "set key=mysecretkey" myencryptedfile
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bad idea. The password will be visible in 'ps' and your bash history.

It is better to do this inside vim, some parts will be unencrypted (viminfo and regular memory). I was incorrect in suggesting you should disable file undo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700389/using-vims-persistent-undo) and swap file (vim -n). See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Encryption.

Most importantly though, as mentioned above, don't put the password in plain sight where it can be viewed with a simple 'ps'.

Comment: How can be recovered?I try to open a undo file file.un~ but is full of strange and impossible to read chars

Answer (score 1):

There is the gnupg.vim plugin (https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645 and https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg).  It transparantly encrypts and decrypts files with gpg.  Is asks the password without loggin it, it associates with .gpg files, i.e.: `vim secret.txt.gpg` opens the file from CLI, asks the password from vim, and allows you to read and edit it.  From within vim `:e secret.txt.gpg` and `:w` work as well asking password and opening respectively writing the file.